# Determine the maximum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

**Problem**: Determine $$\max_{z \in \mathbb{C}, |z|=1} |z^3-z+2|$$

**Solution**: We have $z = \cos t + i \sin t$, and replacing, we get: $$E=|{{z}^{3}}-z+2|=\sqrt{2\left| 1- \cos 2x+2\cos 3x-2\cos x \right|}.$$

Replacing the formula $\cos 2x, \cos 3x$ with the $\cos x$, and denoting $\cos x=t$, we get

$$E=\sqrt{4\left| 4{{t}^{3}}+{{t}^{2}}-2t+1 \right|},t\in \left[ -1,1 \right].$$

Denoting $f(t)=4{{t}^{3}}+{{t}^{2}}-2t+1$, the maximum on $\left[ -1,1 \right]$ yields

$$\max \left\{ f\left( -\frac{1}{2} \right),f(1) \right\} =\max \left\{ \frac{7}{4},4 \right\}=4.$$

Am I right?

Comment: No, it is not correct. The answer is smaller than $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

$E^2 = 4\cos(3x)-2\cos(2x)-4\cos x+6$

reducing to $\cos x$ we have

$$
E^2 = 16\cos^3 x-4\cos^2x-16\cos x+8
$$

and now calling $y = \cos x$ the problem becomes

$$
\max_{y\in [-1,1]}\sqrt{16 y^3-4 y^2-16 y+8}
$$